# Sqlite date comparison in different tables

Tags: sqlite, air

I'm using following query to compare Date values.

```
select *   from OFFER   where date('now') >= Datetime(START_DATE) 
and date('now') <= Datetime(END_DATE)
```

Its working fine..But I cant find the syntax to query the date comparison from another table..

```
 select *   from EMPLOYEE 
where date('now') >= Datetime(VACATIONS.START_DATE)  and date('now') <= Datetime(VACATIONS.END_DATE)`
```

here EMPLOYEE  and VACATIONS are the tabble names..please correct me..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but maybe something like this:

```
SELECT A.* from EMPLOYEE A, VACATIONS B WHERE  
date('now') >= Datetime(B.START_DATE)  
and date('now') <= Datetime(B.END_DATE)
```

Comment: I edited the code a bit..can you try the new query? I think this one should work